# Django translations RTL language

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to set my django project to support Arabic language , but I am still not getting anything right .

## my settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    USE_I18N = True

    LANGUAGES = (

        ('ar', _('Arabic')),
        ('en', _('English')),
    )

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    LOCAL_PATHS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
    )
```

## my index.html

```
{% trans "Hello and welcome" %}
<p>{% blocktrans %}
    hello  dear friends, i would be very happy if you 
    can help!!
{% endblocktrans %}</p> 
</br>
{{ request.LANGUAGE_CODE }}
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),

)
```

## after that to make the .po file I used the command:

```
python manage.py makemessages -l 'ar'
```

and after I get the .po file , i have added my translations in 'msgstr',
then used the following command to compile the translated string :

python manage.py compilemassages

then i logged in , and changed the language code to 'ar',  in the url(127.0.0.1:8000/ar) , but still i am getting the english strings , and not its translation , so any idea about what is that I am doing wrong .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i fixed my mistake and it was just a typo, instead of LOCALE_PATHS , I  wrote LOCAL_PATHS ..
thanks anyway guys